# Ubuntu dpkg broken

Tags: ubuntu, dpkg

I have an Ubuntu installation where /var/lib/dpkg  is empty. Every apt-get command fails with this error :

```
E: Impossible de verrouiller /var/lib/dpkg/status - open (2: Aucun fichier ou dossier de ce type)

(can not lock /var/lib/dpkg/status)
```

Which is not unexpected as the folder is empty.

How can I totally uninstall and reinstall dpkg?

Comment: Please run `LANG=C apt-get update` and update your question with the error message in a locale everybody here can read.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to reinstall `dpkg`, what you need to do is to recover the database of package selections.

This is a use case where a backup might be useful.

If you don't have backups, you can try to copy an old status file from `var/backups/dpkg.status.*` to the original location in `/var/lib/dpkg` and run

```
# apt-get clean && apt-get update
```

If you can't recover an old status file, you can still try to rebuild one:

```
# ls /usr/share/doc | grep -Ev '([A-Z]|^texmf$|^debian$)' | awk '{print $1 " install"}' | dpkg --set-selections
# dselect --expert
```